# How to replace values to binary(0-1) in Pandas for Network data?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science, netflow

I have 75 columns, and 300k captured network traffic CSV file.
I am playing with data to apply ML. I need to convert IP addresses to 1 and 0 according to internal and external.
So if it is

```
10.0.2.* > 0
others > 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
I was doing the manually replace method.

```
df['SrcAddr'] = df['SrcAddr'].replace(['10.0.2.15','10.0.2.2'],[0,0,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['SrcAddr'] = df['SrcAddr'].str.startswith('10.0.2.').rsub(1)
```

or with a regex:

```
df['SrcAddr'] = df['SrcAddr'].str.fullmatch('10\.0\.2\.').rsub(1)
```

How it works: for each match this returns `True`, using `rsub(1)` we compute `1-True -> 0` and for each non-match `1-False -> 1`

Alternative with `np.where` for using any value:

```
df['SrcAddr'] = np.where(df['SrcAddr'].str.startswith('10.0.2.'), 0, 1)
```

example (as new column):

```
     SrcAddr  SrcAddr2
0  10.0.2.42         0
1    8.8.8.8         1
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not this method! For other values, should I use if condition?

Comment: No, this handles directly the others, I'll add an example

Comment: df['SrcAddr'] = df['SrcAddr'].str.startswith('10.0.2.').rsub(0) should be like this, right? Because I want internal IPs to be 0, external 1.
Thank you for your example. just saw it!

Comment: No, try it ;) I'll provide an alternative

Comment: Yes, it worked! Omg, what a easy! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a few details on the logic